# A to Z list for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

Anyone know a plugin or any other solution to list posts filtered by the first letter from custom post types? I found some plugins, but nothing seems to work with custom post types.

Answer (score 1):

[Post Types Order](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-types-order/)

While not specifically for ordering from A to Z, features an easy drag-and-drop interface for ordering your Posts. It can be applied to any Post Type you create.

So your changes won't be automatic, but can easily be applied.